Structuring an Expo Application with Tab Navigation, Onboarding Screens, and Dynamic Routing
I'm developing an Expo application that requires a structured setup using Expo's latest features, including app routing, file-based routing, and dynamic routes. I want to implement the following features and am seeking guidance on how to structure my project effectively:
Onboarding Screens:
The app should start with an initial screen displaying a "Hello" message for 30 seconds. Users can skip this screen to proceed.
The next screen should also display a "Hello" message for 30 seconds, with a "Skip" option to move to the sign-up page.
The sign-up page should include a link to the login page for users who already have an account.
Authenticated User Flow:
Upon successful login, users should be navigated to a main screen with 4 tabs: Home, Wallet, Orders, and Profile.
Tab Navigation:
Each tab should have multiple nested pages. For example:
Home Tab: Includes pages such as Settings, Order Details, Product Details.
Wallet Tab: Includes Wallet Details and other relevant pages.
Orders Tab: Includes Order Details and related pages.
Profile Tab: Includes Profile Settings and other profile-related pages.
Requirements:
Utilize Expo's latest app routing features, including app routing, file-based routing, and dynamic routes.
Follow best practices for clean codebase architecture and maintainability.
How should I structure my Expo application to achieve this setup?
Could you provide an example or outline for a clean project structure, including key components and configuration details?

i have no idea routing structure


Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
